# SAS PROC IMPORT not creating OUT dataset as commanded

Tags: import, sas, netezza, enterprise-guide

**Situation**: I'm importing an xlsx file with PROC IMPORT and wanting to send the data OUT to a new netezza database table.

**My issue**: SAS appears to run fine, but the log shows a completely different table name was been created with a libref that I'm not using (and this libref is cleared).

```
LIBNAME abc sasionza server=server database=db port=123 user=user pass=pass;
PROC IMPORT
    OUT = abc.DesiredTableName
    DATAFILE= "my/excelfile/file.xlsx"
    DBMS=xlsx
    REPLACE;
    SHEET="Sheet1";
    GETNAMES=YES;
RUN;
```

This "runs" just fine, or so it appears to. I check the log and I see this:

> NOTE: The import data set has 11 observations and 7 variables.
>   NOTE: ***xyz*.ATableCreatedDaysAgoInAnotherProgram** data set was successfully created. NOTE: PROCEDURE IMPORT used (Total process time):
>          real time           0.55 seconds
>          cpu time            0.02 seconds

I thought, hmm, that is weird. libref **xyz** is actually cleared, so I couldn't possibly use it, and **ATableCreatedDaysAgoInAnotherProgram** is a tablename used in a completely different SAS E-Guide program I have going on.

Sounds like a memory or cache issue. So, I close all instances of SAS E-Guide and fire up a new one. I created a new program that only has my desired lines (the code listed above).

It runs, and I get the following log as a result:

> NOTE: The import data set has 11 observations and 7 variables.
>   NOTE: ***WORK*._PRODSAVAIL** data set was successfully created.
>   NOTE: PROCEDURE IMPORT used (Total process time):
>          real time           0.55 seconds
>          cpu time            0.02 seconds

I will note that this is the first time I've actually tried to use PROC IMPORT to send something directly to a netezza table. Up until now, I've always imported files into WORK and worked with them for a bit before inserting them into a table in a database. I thought that maybe this is a SAS limitation I may not be aware of, but the SAS documentation for PROC IMPORT (https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/proc/z0308090.htm) says that you can specify a two level name in the OUT statement, so I feel that this should work. If it **can't** work, then I feel that SAS should error out instead of randomly creating a table name that I'm not even executing in my code.

**Summary (tl;dr)**:    Can you PROC IMPORT directly into a netezza database table using a libref? And if you can't, why is my code executing and producing text that isn't even related to what I'm doing?

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: You have some issue with the `out` table name, a serious one apparently.  Please post the actual code and complete log.

Comment: Sorry, I have to make the posted code extremely generic as to not share an ounce of anything job related. I will go and add the double quotes to the datafile path though, thanks for point that one out for me.

I have actually found a solution as well, which I will post shortly. Thanks again!

Comment: What happens if you first import to a WORK dataset and then use a simple DATA step to write to the Netezza database?  Does that work? Does it produce a valid error message?  Does it only do when importing from XLSX file? Or do you see the same thing when importing a delimited file?

Comment: What if you eliminate PROC IMPORT and instead use a LIBNAME to point to the XLSX file so that you can use a data step to copy the data?

Comment: @Tom I discovered the issue when I imported to a WORK dataset and then tried to use PROC SQL to create a table. That is when I received a CLI error about finding a word out of place. That error made me realize the issue was from the multi-word column name. From there, I cleaned up the column names in the xlsx file, went back to my original PROC IMPORT directly OUT to netezza, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Solution**: **A column in the xlsx file being imported had a space in one of the column names...** Simply removing the space in the column name and saving the changes to the xlsx file allowed for the PROC IMPORT code above to be executed flawlessly with the desired results being imported into the named netezza table.

**NOTE:** This fixed my problem, but it does not explain the SAS log showing text executing that wasn't actually in the code to be executed.

Comment: What setting do you have for the VALIDVARNAME option?

Comment: I have to assume VALIDVARNAME is whatever the system default is for that, as I have not specified anything for that option.

Comment: Does NETEZZA allow spaces in variable names?

Comment: I'm glad you found your answer, but this is not a good answer as you've written it.  Please remove the editorializing and focus on the actual problem/solution.

Comment: Re `options validvarname`, that's probably your issue.  EG uses `validvarname=any` as a default, which I find somewhat strange, but what can you do.

Comment: @Tom I don't believe column names can have spaces in netezza tables

Comment: @Joe I limited the answer to just the straight forward fix to the issue.

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should report the issue with not getting a working ERROR message to SAS.

To make sure that your SAS/Netezza tables do not have variable names with spaces in them change the setting of the VALIDVARNAME option before running your program. That way PROC IMPORT will convert your column headings in the XLSX file into valid variable names.

```
options validvarname=v7;
libname out ...... ;
proc import out=out.table replace ...
```

Comment: The issue has been reported to SAS. Their solution: reboot.
Thanks for the tip with validvarname. I was unaware of this option, it appears to force the names into something netezza accepts. I really wish the log would have led us here to this column name issue. That is very bizarre.

Comment: How did they say that rebooting would fix the issue?  Were you able to send them a simple program that would recreate the issue?

Comment: the idea was that the text the log was generating was from some sort of a corrupted cache file, or something stored in memory went awry.

We did send SAS the exact code (not generalized like I had posted in here) that was causing the issue. At the end of the day, the code was sound. This was SAS not being able to notify us of an error, which is scary. I have to wonder if it was just wrongly displaying text in the log, or if it was trying to create a table that I did not tell it to create. FYI, SAS wasn't able to actually create the table it claimed to be creating with the wrong name.

Comment: Yet another reason not to use PROC IMPORT.